# search query count 1 field group by name

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I've been using to my query, but I can't seem to find my expected result. maybe my query is wrong.

table attempts

```
|ID | name | results   
| 1 | Paul | Passed        
| 2 | Paul | Passed   
| 3 | Paul | Failed            
| 4 | John | Failed   
| 5 | John | Passed
```

the result should be

```
name | passed |  Failed  | 
Paul |   2    |    1     |   
John |   1    |    1     |
```

but my result is 4 rows. displaying their names twice.

here's my query

```
SELECT name,
SUM( results =  "Passed" ) AS passed,
SUM( results = "Failed" ) AS failed
FROM attempts
GROUP BY results, name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `results` from the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name,
SUM( results =  "Passed" ) AS passed,
SUM( results = "Failed" ) AS failed
FROM attempts
GROUP BY name
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00077a/2)

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
SELECT name, SUM( results =  "Passed" ) AS passed,
SUM( results = "Failed" ) AS failed
FROM attempt
GROUP BY name
```

## [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40848/2)

[image]